# Manhwa about a woman who is reincarnated after a car accident

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I read this manhwa just a few days ago I forgot it’s title, it was about a woman who was in a car accident then reincarnated into a story she made when she was 14. I remember some things in it, her mother was a mistress or concubine idk  of the duke and she had a brother and he also had to become temporary duke because brother is not at age that’s all I remember

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. This is a very common trope (isekai'd into a story that they wrote) and any additional info will help to identify it.

Comment: If you read this in a browser, can you check your browser history?